# Реализация Unit of work в Asp.Net core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Добрый день!
Можете рассказать о реализации паттерна Unit Of Work в среде ASP.NET Core

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/312214/

Comment: @vitidev: Из всей этой статьи мне кажется наиболее полезным [комментарий](https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/312214/#comment_9855696): «Если посмотреть на EF со стороны, то DbContext — это и есть UnitOfWork, а DataSet — репозитории.»

Comment: (вот [длинное обсуждение](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37682/orm-vs-repository) по теме с разными мнениями)

Comment: @VladD Нужно по другому задавать вопрос "что такого особенного в core, чтобы именно в нем этот паттерн реализовывался как то особенно". Лично я не в курсе

Comment: @vitidev: Держу пари, особенности именно ASP.NET, да ещё и Core 1.0 автору вопроса в реальности не так уж и важны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

каждая repository дает работать с единицу информации:это единица может быть например один таблица или связанные таблицы или может быть другой контейнер информации
.обязанности паттерна  Unit Of Work : связывать эти repository в одном логически связанным контейнере и содержать в себе те функсионали который относится в абстрактном манере для всех репозиторий. Например в какой то момент времени мы должны сохранить изменяемое Entities.тогда u Unit of Work'a  должен быть метод **Save()** 
Вот кусок кода из моей реальный программы:

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IEventRepository Events { get; set; }
       Task<int> SaveAsync();
        int Save();
    }


//Isolation from Concrete Info Container
    public interface IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryType> where TPrimaryType : struct where TEntity : class
    {
        Task<TEntity> GetAsync(TPrimaryType id);
         Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync();
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        Task AddAsync(TEntity entity);
        Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

        void Remove(TEntity entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    }


public class Repository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TPrimaryKey : struct where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly AccreditationDbContext Context;

        public Repository(AccreditationDbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets Item by id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(TPrimaryKey id)
        {
            return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get All Data as List
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await Context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds data using Expression tree predicate
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets first item matching predicate
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return await Context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add data to Context
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
           await Context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add data range to Context
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities"></param>
        public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            await Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRangeAsync(entities);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove data from Context
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove range of data from Context
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities"></param>
        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
        }

    }

 public interface IEventRepository : IRepository<Event,int>,IDbDependency<Event>
    {
        //TODO: add Event methods
    }


  public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly AccreditationDbContext _context;
        public IEventRepository Events { get; set; }

        public UnitOfWork(AccreditationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Events = new EventRepository(_context);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }

        public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
        {
          return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        public int Save()
        {
           return _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Из вашего кода отлично видно, что реализация Unit Of Work свелась к обертке поверх готовой реализации Unit Of Work в виде контекста. Т.е. вы применили не SRP (который тут вообще никак не проявлен, максимум "ответственность класса UnitOfWork - приклеивание интерфейса IUnitOfWork к классу с готовой реализации его в EF"), а Interface Segregation

Comment: "связывать эти repository в одном логически связанным контейнере и содержать в себе те функсионали который относится в абстрактном манере для всех репозиторий" - именно это делает класс-контекст в EF :)