# Актуальность Unit Of Work и Репозиториев в ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Раньше, на .NET Framework MVC 5, я использовал трёхуровневую архитектуру вместе с паттернами `Unit Of Work` и `Репозиторием`. Также использовал `Dependency Injection`. Сейчас я хочу сделать простое приложение с CRUD контроллером на ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI и Angular 6, для себя, но уровня продакшен. Буду использовать code-first EF и БД MSSQL Server.

Естественно, в актуальности трёхуровневой архитектуры я не сомневась, но теперь устанавливать контейнер DI нет смысла, так как он уже поддерживается с коробки. Также у меня возникаю сомнения в надобности собственной реализации `Unit Of Work` и `Репозитория`, как я понял, EF уже реализует эти паттерны ([операясь на этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715106/180980)).

Собственно вопрос, актуальность собственной реализации `Unit Of Work` и `Репозитория`, и какие вещи будут правильными для проекта уровня продакшен? Плюсом будет ссылки на литературу по имплементации всего это в ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Обычно нужны свои репозитории, когда появляется логика. Запись в лог при сохранении, обновление каких то свойств при сохранении, создание отдельных записей при специфических изменениях - куда писать весь такой код? Кто проконтролирует вызов всего этого кода? Вот тут и помогает репозиторий.

Comment: @Monk репозитории сделаны только для взаимодействия с БД, разве нет? Вся остольная логика в серсисах, в уровне бизнес-логики.

Comment: Ну надо вам сделать в сущности событие "перед сохранением" или "перед удалением". Кто, кроме репозитория, может обеспечить вызов такого события?

Comment: @Monk в классе нашего контекста оверайднуть `SaveChanges()` и там логировать в одном месте, а не плодить логику логирования в репозиториях.

Comment: Ну, если устроит такой вариант, то я например больше причин заводить отдельный свой репозиторий - не вижу.

Comment: Вот хороший цикл статей по созданию приложения [.NET Core Series](https://code-maze.com/net-core-series/)